# Where did all these widgetset files come from?

Tags: java, git, vaadin

I have a project that I usually do work on with at my work. The project is using Git repository.

When I synchronized the workspace on my laptop and pull from the stream, I'm seeing a whole bunch of files that I've never seen in the Git staging area.

I compared the files and it has some content in it but before there was nothing. I don't want to commit it if it isn't necessary

[image]

Comment: Those are the result of the [widgetset compilation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/addons/addons-maven.html) which usually changes when adding/removing/updating Vaadin addons or changing the Vaadin framework version. It's not necessary to commit them if the build process compiles the widget before creating the release-package. Maybe someone pushed them by mistake or to save some time (compilation may take some time and is not required before every run, just when something changes as stated before). Simplest way to find out is to check the history and ask the person directly :-)

Comment: @Morfic Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Morfic Hey sorry for bringing up the question again but it's kind of bothering me. I'm the only one working on the project. I don't want to commit to the files and I also don't want to add them to the git.ignore file either. If I just delete all the changes will that be ok? Because before there was nothing in them and now their are a bunch of weird symbols

Comment: @Morfic I just said screw it and deleted and copied the repository again.

Comment: :-) No problem you can delete them for sure. At most, when running your app, it will complain that it can't find some JS, but like I said they will be re-generated when compiling the widgetset (eg: mvn vaadin:clean vaadin:compile). **P.S.** I always add the `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets` to `.ignore` so I won't have to worry about it any longer. The build server/process will be compiling the widgetset and packaging the result in the final artifact any way.

Comment: @Morfic Thanks for the help man!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I'll see when I have the time to summarise the above in an answer for anyone else looking for the same thing. Or you could do it yourself, and choose your own answer as the correct one after a couple of days

Comment: @Morfic I can do it, no worries. Thanks again